# Determine if a widget is showing in the viewport in GWT

Tags: gwt, widget, viewport

Is it possible to determine wether or not a specific widget is showing in the viewport?

I want to start loading more data once the last widget in my listwidget is displayed to the user. I figured I could handle scroll events and for every event check if the last widget is displayed and the fire of an rpc to get more data.

BR

Answer (score 1):

Here's the GWT method that does the Job (it is translated from the JQuery solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scroling)).

```
/**
 * @param widget the widget to check
 * @return true if the widget is in the visible part of the page
 */
private boolean isScrolledIntoView(Widget widget) {
    if (widget != null) {
        int docViewTop = Window.getScrollTop();
        int docViewBottom = docViewTop + Window.getClientHeight();
        int elemTop = widget.getAbsoluteTop();
        int elemBottom = elemTop + widget.getOffsetHeight();
        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }       
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `ShowMorePagerPanel` from the [GWT Showcase's `CellList` sample](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList).

You can use the widget's `getElement()`'s `getOffsetTop()` and the scrolling element's `getScrollTop()` (equivalent to `getVerticalScrollPosition()` for a `ScrollPanel`) to compute whether the widget is currently *in view* (beware of the elements' `getOffsetParent()` though, you might want to set the scrolling element's CSS `position` to `relative` to make it the *offset parent* of the widget)